# Split the string of text file and store it in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a text file which has data as follows:

```
Surrender~abc~nov@2012
Surrender~bnc~bhdgvx
Surrender~nkhjb~bcdjh
.
.
.
```

I want to separate the data row by row and store second and third column values in Hashmap as 2nd -> key and 3rd -> value and check if the value entered by user exist in the Hashmap and return true.

I tried following but getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`..Please guide.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Surrender.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    String[] parts = strLine.split("~");
    for (int i = 0; i <= parts.length; i++) {
       if(!parts[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Surrender")){
    String key=parts[i];
    String value=parts[i++];
    if(key!=null && value!=null)
    hm.put(key,value);
}
    }
}

System.out.println("HashMap size..." + hm.size());
in.close();
```

Comment: Don't use the Hashmap without type parameters. also you increment `i` within the loop also, therefore overstepping array bounds.

Comment: `i <= parts.length` ... Edit : and ++i doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each of your lines looks like this:

```
Surrender~abc~nov@2012
```

there are three parts after splitting by `~`:

- `Surrender`
- `abc`
- `nov@2012`

These parts are numberd from `0` to `2`.

**Solution:** Don't loop over the `parts`. Do this instead:

```
hm.put(parts[1], parts[2]);
```

**Drop** these lines:

```
for (int i=0;i<=parts.length;i++) {
    if (!parts[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Surrender")) {
        hm.put(parts[i], parts[++i]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Use a generic `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>(); // Java 7
```

Comment: Still it's worth checking the size of `parts` array. When line is badly formatted he will still get that exception.

Comment: @MaciejZiarko True. The data provided in the question is always three parts long, though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= parts.length; i++) {
    if (!parts[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Surrender")) {
        hm.put(parts[i], parts[++i]);
    }
}
```

with

```
if (parts.length > 2 && !parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Surrender")) {
    hm.put(parts[1], parts[2]);
}
```

If The data provided in the question is always three parts long you can skip `parts.length > 2`

Comment: Also, declare your `HashMap` as Generic, and use `Map` as reference type like this: - `Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();`. It is considered as good practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, please use types on your HashMap...

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Second, why loop through the split array if its fixed size? I also believe you create problems for yourself when you access an element with [++i], which increments your counter. On the last iteration of the loop through the split, this may put it out of bounds.

Try something like:

```
if (parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Surrender")) {
    hm.put(parts[1], parts[2]);
}
```